# When I say throughout this paper in the introduction, do I include the introduction and the abstract?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-requests

In the introduction of a research paper, we give something many definitions. Then I want to just focus on one definition among the definitions mentioned in the introduction; I.e. The paper is discussing only one definition. So at the end of the introduction, I say "throughout this paper ... means .... ". I am asking if this is a proper way to express what I mean. If I say throughout the paper, do I include the introduction or not? How about the abstract which is before the introduction?

Comment: IMO the introduction giving all the definitions then saying "in this paper X means yada, yada, yada" is a nice way to explain. It shows you understand there is more than one definition of the word and that you are focusing on just one of those, as opposed to just making a random definition up.

Comment: I believe that this question is not focused on whether the introduction should contain definition(s), but whether the introduction should say "throughout this paper" versus "throughout ***the main body of*** this paper", to clarify that it's not referring to itself (and the abstract) — *or* should it say "throughout this paper ***and this introduction and the abstract***"?  While this is the site to ask about the nuances of English words, [Academia Stack Exchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask about the conventions for terminology in research papers.

Comment: @Scott Sensible observation. This really is a point of academic protocol, and also a good one. I have no idea how to move it, however. Can I in some sense, by doing _**this**_, encourage its being shifted to Academia, where loads of us will usefully jump on it?

Comment: The thing to do is to click on "flag" → "in need of moderator intervention" and then just say something like "please migrate this to Academia Stack Exchange".  But (1) I believe that this should be user113715's decision, and (2) since this question is marginally on-topic here on EL&U, I suggest that it should be left here for 24 to 48 hours to see what answers it gets, before talking about migrating it.  @user113715: Please do not just re-ask the question on Academia Stack Exchange; follow the procedures.

Comment: You may want to ask this at academics.SE

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not have to worry about the Abstract.  That is a *massive* distillation of your paper, and should describe the overall shape of your entire argument, not the detail at all.  In a broad fashion, your Abstract should give *everything* away, showing where you will get to, using whatever tools you have chosen.

Less generally, your Introduction should give everything away as well, but with more of a detailed roadmap. You are literally *introducing* the reader to your work, welcoming an interested person to the detail that you are about to show them.

Do not try to disguise things for dramatically unveiling later. (That is a common error that you seem not to be making, but it needed to be mentioned.) Use your Introduction to do exactly what it says: introduce the reader to what is to come, and encourage them to look forward to this unexpected route to where you will end up together.

Writing your Conclusion is a parallel skill.  In a well-written paper, your Conclusion should show that you have delivered what the Introduction promised. 'Wa-hay!!  We're here!! Told you so!!'

Wrestle through the paper first, and then (of course) write the Conclusion, which might might end up not being the one you originally expected. Then (after a bit of a pause) write an Introduction to alert the reader to the path you have found.